# Killing and recreating an activity in a service in android development

Tags: android, android-activity

I am newbie in android development. So I need help .

i would like to display an activity when phone state is ringing, and kill this activity when state is idle or offhook.

So I built a class extends Broadcastreceiver. I call myphonestatelistener class extends PhoneStateListener . Also i create an activity named ringingactivity.

Here is my code (MyPhoneStateListener):

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){



    switch(state)
    {
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
            Intent killIntentidle = new Intent();
            killIntentidle.setAction("RingingOver") ;
            ctx.sendBroadcast(killIntentidle);                

            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");    
            Intent killIntent = new Intent();
            killIntent.setAction("RingingOver") ;
            ctx.sendBroadcast(killIntent);      

            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
           Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");    
           Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(ctx , RingingActivity.class) ;
           dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           ctx.startActivity(dialogIntent);            

           break;
    }
}
```

In my tests, i call emulator from telnet and it succesfully display activity when it is ringing. When i accept or decline call, activity is finished . But when i call emulator again, activity could not be recreated again. I cant see it on the screen. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my activity code :

public class RingingActivity extends Activity {

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();


    }   
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.ringing_activity);

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

       filter.addAction("RingingOver");
       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
       //registerReceiver(receiver,filter) ;

}


public void finish() {

    super.finish();        
};
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure as why you need to call Garbage Collector. Please try to fix the root cause as why, activity is not created; sometimes. First analyze the issue by putting logs in your  MyPhoneStateListener and RingingActivity. In MyPhoneStateListener, do print the state of RingingActivity activity, before taking any action (Start/kill activity).

Comment: Ok Munish, i'll try to find problem with logging. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hi cergun, do you find my above reply as nonconstructive Or offensive.

Comment: Hi Munish, i think your reply is good for me. Also i found the problem with logging.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is in your MyPhoneStateListener code. The other code look O.K to me.

Some how your PhoneStateListener is not alive next time. Are you able to see "RINGING" logs for second time?

Comment: Hi, because of the character limitation. I post my code as an answer.thanks.

Comment: I wrote it works in each call. But when i test it deeply. It sometimes not create activity .

Answer (score -2):

Thank you very much for your reply Munish Katoch. I have a solution but not sure if i find the right solution . when I use Garbage Collecter , activity could be seen in screen in each calling. 
Here is my code :

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

```
Context ctx ;
private boolean iscalling ; 

MyPhoneStateListener(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx ;
}

public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){



    switch(state)
    {
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
            if(iscalling == true)
            {
            Intent killIntentidle = new Intent();
            killIntentidle.setAction("RingingOver") ;
            ctx.sendBroadcast(killIntentidle);                
            System.gc() ;
            iscalling = false ;
            }
            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");    
            if(iscalling == true)
            {                
            Intent killIntent = new Intent();
            killIntent.setAction("RingingOver") ;
            ctx.sendBroadcast(killIntent);      
            System.gc() ;
            iscalling = false ;
            }
            break;
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
           Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
           iscalling = true ;
           Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(ctx , RingingActivity.class) ;
           dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           ctx.startActivity(dialogIntent);            
           System.gc() ;
           break;
    }
}
```

}